# `tf.keras.model.evaluate()` provides different results when fed the same data in different formats

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

## Backgound

I am looking at the following Tensorflow time series tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#single-shot_models

For the discussion here, I am going to consider the ‘multi_linear_model’ in the **Multi-step models** section.

I add the following line

`multi_val_performance_new['Linear'] = multi_linear_model.evaluate(next(iter(multi_window.val))[0], next(iter(multi_window.val))[1])`

after this line

`multi_val_performance['Linear'] = multi_linear_model.evaluate(multi_window.val)`.

When I inspect the loss and mean absolute errors, they are different.

## Question

Why - when I feed the original `tf.Dataset` to `model.evaluate` - do I get one set of loss and mean absolute error, but when I feed its components - `(next(iter(tf.Dataset))[0], next(iter(tf.Dataset)[1])` to `model.evaluate` - do I get a different set of loss and mean absolute errors?

### NB

I have set `shuffle = false` in `def make_dataset(self, data):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next(iter(ds))` will only return one batch/observation. Passing the entire dataset in `model.evaluate` will return the metrics for the entire dataset.